# Functions to count vowels and consonants in strings

Tags: c++, beginner, strings

I am coming to a problem where I am  writing a function that accepts a pointer to a C-string as its argument. The function should count the number of vowels appearing in the string and return that number. Then, I am writing another function that accepts a pointer to a C-string as its argument. This function should count the number of consonants appearing in the string and return that number.

Am I violating any of the following restrictions?

- No global variables
- No labels or go-to statements
- No infinite loops, examples include: for(;;), while(1), while(true), do{//code}while(1);
- No break statements to exit loops

Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

//Function prototypes
int Vowel_count( char *str);

int Consonant_count(char *str);

 int main()

    {

     char String[30];

     char choice;

     int Nvowels,Nconsonant;

     //Input a string

     cout<<"Enter a string:";

     cin.getline(String ,30);

     do

     {

     //Displaying Menu

     cout<<"\nMENU"<<endl;

     cout<<" (A) Count the number of vowels in the string"<<endl;

     cout<<" (B) Count the number of Consonants in the string"<<endl;

     cout<<" (C) Count both the vowels and consonants in the string"<<endl;

     cout<<" (D) Enter another string"<<endl;

     cout<<" (E) Exit program"<<endl;

     //Inputting choice

      cout<<"Enter choice";

     cin>>choice;

     switch(choice)

     {

     case 'A':
     //Function call to get number of Vowels

               Nvowels=Vowel_count(String);  
                cout<<"Number of vowels is:"<<Nvowels<<endl;

              break;

     case 'B': 
     //Function call to get number of consonants

                Nconsonant=Consonant_count(String);

                //Outputting number of Consonants

               cout<<"Number of Consonants is:"<<Nconsonant<<endl;

                 break;

     case 'C': 
     //Function call to get number of Vowels

                Nvowels=Vowel_count(String);

                //Function call to get number of consonants

                Nconsonant=Consonant_count(String);

              //Outputting Both Vowels and Consonants

              cout<<"Number of vowels is:"<<Nvowels<<endl;

                   cout<<"Number of Consonants is:"<<Nconsonant<<endl;

                 break;

     case 'D': //Inputting another string

                 cout<<"Enter another String:";

                 fflush(stdin);

                 cin.getline(String ,30);

                 break;

     case 'E': exit(0);

                  break;  

     }//End of Switch

     }while(choice !='E');//End Do while

    //Pause system for a while

     system("pause");

}//End main

//Function Definitions

int Vowel_count( char *str)

{  

   int count=0;//Local variable

   //Checks for all characters in C-string

   while(*str!='\0')

   {

    if(*str=='a'||*str=='e'||*str=='i'||*str=='o'||*str=='u')

         count++;

         str++;

   }//End While

//Returns count value to function call

   return count;

}//End of Vowel_count

int Consonant_count(char *str)

{

int count=0;

    //Checks for all characters in C-string

     while(*str!='\0')

     { //Checks for consonants

     if(*str!='a'&&*str!='e'&&*str!='i'&&*str!='o'&&*str!='u')

          count++;

        str++;

     }//End While

     //Returns count value to function call

     return count;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a number of things that may help you improve your program.

### Don't abuse `using namespace std`

Putting `using namespace std` at the top of every program is [a bad habit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) that you'd do well to avoid.  Know when to use it and when not to (as when writing include headers).

### Don't use `system("pause")`

There are two reasons not to use `system("cls")` or `system("pause")`.  The first is that it is not portable to other operating systems which you may or may not care about now.  The second is that it's a security hole, which you absolutely **must** care about.  Specifically, if some program is defined and named `cls` or `pause`, your program will execute that program instead of what you intend, and that other program could be anything.  First, isolate these into a seperate functions `cls()` and `pause()` and then modify your code to call those functions instead of `system`.  Then rewrite the contents of those functions to do what you want using C++.  For example, for `pause` you might use this:

```
void pause()
{
    std::string;
    std::cout << "Press enter to continue...\n";
    std::cin >> foo;
}
```

### Use consistent formatting

The code as posted has inconsistent indentation which makes it hard to read and understand. Pick a style and apply it consistently.

### Don't use `std::endl` if you don't really need it

The difference betweeen `std::endl` and `'\n'` is that `'\n'` just emits a newline character, while `std::endl` actually flushes the stream.  This can be time-consuming in a program with a lot of I/O and is rarely actually needed.  It's best to *only* use `std::endl` when you have some good reason to flush the stream and it's not very often needed for simple programs such as this one.  Avoiding the habit of using `std::endl` when `'\n'` will do will pay dividends in the future as you write more complex programs with more I/O and where performance needs to be maximized.

### Use string concatenation

The menu includes these lines:

```
cout<<"\nMENU"<<endl;
cout<<" (A) Count the number of vowels in the string"<<endl;
cout<<" (B) Count the number of Consonants in the string"<<endl;
cout<<" (C) Count both the vowels and consonants in the string"<<endl;
cout<<" (D) Enter another string"<<endl;
cout<<" (E) Exit program"<<endl;
```

Each of those is a separate call to `operator<<` but they don't need to be.  Another way to write that would be like this:

```
std::cout << 
    "\nMENU\n"
    " (A) Count the number of vowels in the string\n"
    " (B) Count the number of Consonants in the string\n"
    " (C) Count both the vowels and consonants in the string\n"
    " (D) Enter another string\n"
    " (E) Exit program\n"
    "Enter choice\n";
```

This reduces the entire menu to a single call to `operator<<` because consecutive strings in C++ (and in C, for that matter) are automatically concatenated into a single string by the compiler.

### Check your `if` statements for proper braces

I suspect that the `if` statement in the `Vowel_count()` routine is not what you intended to write.  It's written like this:

```
if(*str=='a'||*str=='e'||*str=='i'||*str=='o'||*str=='u')
    count++;
    str++;
```

but because there are no braces, what's actually being executed is this:

```
if(*str=='a'||*str=='e'||*str=='i'||*str=='o'||*str=='u') {
    count++;
}
str++;
```

That is the correct operation, but it's confusing to the reader.  I recommend using the braces always to avoid ambiguity or confusion.

### Use `const` where possible

The `Vowel_count` and `Consonant_count` functions do not (and should not) alter the passed `char *`, so that parameter should be passed as `const`.

### Fix the bug

If the user enters the string `"My dog has fleas."`, the program will report 4 vowels and 13 consonants, but that's not actually correct.  The `'y'` in "My" is a vowel in this usage and the spaces and period are not consonants.

Comment: Thanks @Edward for the helpful tips. I will def. fix it. But, does it apply to the restrictions I have above? Or Program free from those restrictions?

Comment: Yes, it appears to comply with the stated restrictions.  Also, I should mention that those restrictions are *generally good programming practices*, so keep them in mind for future programs as well.

Comment: Determining whether `y` is acting as a consonant or as a vowel adds complexity, but perhaps it's an interesting problem for a [tag:beginner]...

Answer (score 3):

```
    char String[30];
    char choice;
    int Nvowels,Nconsonant;
```

Don't define a variable before it is needed. Doing so increases the cognitive load on readers that trace through your code and keep mental records of every variable, their possible values, and whether they've even been set. This artifact from older languages also encourages lazy reuse of variables beyond their original intent. Define variables as you need them and keep the scope of each variable as narrow as required.

Use descriptive names. The larger the scope in which a variable exists, the more important it is to give that variable a name that indicates to the reader what it represents. `String` \$\rightarrow\$ `input_sentence`. `Nvowels` \$\rightarrow\$ `vowel_count`.

---

```
    cin.getline(String ,30);
```

If a user inputs 30 or more characters, [`std::istream::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline) will set the `failbit`. If *end-of-file* is reached before the delimiter is encountered, `std::istream::getline` will set the `eofbit`. You should check if `std::cin` is in a readable state and reset the state if it's not, otherwise you'll have an infinite loop when an error is encountered.

---

```
    cout<<"\nMENU"<<endl;
    cout<<" (A) Count the number of vowels in the string"<<endl;
    cout<<" (B) Count the number of Consonants in the string"<<endl;
    cout<<" (C) Count both the vowels and consonants in the string"<<endl;
    cout<<" (D) Enter another string"<<endl;
    cout<<" (E) Exit program"<<endl;
```

Whitespace is great for readability as they help separate operators and language constructs.

Avoid `std::endl`. If you need to explicitly flush the cache, then explicitly stream the manipulator [`std::flush`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/flush) and comment why a flush is necessary. If you simply need a *end-of-line* character, prefer '\n' or "\n".

Edward covered string concatenation via the compiler, but I'd like to also point out that C++11 introduced [raw string literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal).

```
    std::cout << R"(
MENU
 (A) Count the number of vowels in the string
 (B) Count the number of Consonants in the string
 (C) Count both the vowels and consonants in the string
 (D) Enter another string
 (E) Exit program
Enter Choice
");
```

---

```
    cin>>choice;
```

As with `std::istream::getline`, [`std::istream::operator>>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt) needs to be checked to ensure a read was successful. If extraction failed, you should probably notify the user and attempt to recover.

---

```
    case 'A':
    //Function call to get number of Vowels
    case 'B':
    //Function call to get number of consonants
    //Outputting number of Consonants
    case 'C':
    //Function call to get number of Vowels
```

Keep comments crisp. Everything I need to know as far as what is being done is already there in the form of code to be compiled. Comments should be reserved for explaining why the code was written the way it was (the intent). Adding verbosity slows down understanding.

To assist with the readability, consider mapping the character inputs to enumerations. You can read up on enum serialization, but just to give you an idea of how it can help readability:

```
enum class Selected {
    count_vowels = 'A',
    count_consonants,
    count_both,
    reset_sentence,
    exit
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, Selected op) {
    // exercise for the reader. 
}

int main() {
    // ...
        Selected user_choice;
        std::cout << "Enter choice: ";
        std::cin >> user_choice;

        switch (user_choice) {
        case Selected::count_vowels:
            // ...
        case Selected::count_consonants:
            // ...
        case Selected::count_both:
            // ...
        case Selected::reset_sentence:
            // ...
        case Selected::exit:
            // ...
        case default:
            // Handle user-input error (out of range, end of file)
```

---

```
            fflush(stdin);
```

Using [`std::fflush`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fflush) on an input stream is [***undefined behavior***](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). If you were trying to reset the buffer of `std::cin`, see [`std::cin::ignore`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore).

---

```
        case 'E': 
            exit(0);
            break;
        }
    } while (choice != 'E');

    system("pause");
```

Once the the program encounters `exit(0)`, all of the remaining code (`break;` \$\rightarrow\$ `while (choice != 'E')` \$\rightarrow\$ `system("pause");`) is unreachable. If you intend to immediately return from a function (or in this case exit the program), you don't need to loop until `choice` is \$E\$. This is one of those times where `while (true)` is actually appropriate if you didn't have the restriction.

`system("pause")` is slow, platform-dependent, and insecure.  Consider re-evaluating your development environment, from having permanent access to a console or utilizing the breakpoint of a debugger.

---

```
int Consonant_count(char *str) {
    // ...
        if (*str != 'a' && *str != 'e' && *str != 'i' && *str != 'o' && *str != 'u')
              count++;
            str++;
```

Prefer scoping your single-line statement blocks with braces. Adding code in a hurry

```
if (condition)
    statement;
  statementIntendedToBeScoped???
```

or commenting

```
if (condition)
    // statement
statementThatIsNowScopedToCondition
```

can lead to errors. Scoping with braces addresses this issue.

```
if (condition) {
    statement
}
statementDefinitelyNotScoped

if (condition) {
    // statement
}
statementDefinitelyNotScoped
```

---

```
if (*str != 'a' && *str != 'e' && *str != 'i' && *str != 'o' && *str != 'u')
```

Keep in mind the various possible values a type can represent. A character (`char`) can represent the set of consonants and vowels (A-Z, a-z). It can also represent digits, punctuation, control characters, whitespace, etc. The conditional in `Consonant_count` is returning true or false if the current character is any ASCII character (not any alphabetic character) that is not any of `aeiou`. Clearly control structures, punctuation, and whitespaces are not consonants.

In both of your functions, how do you handle uppercase vowel inputs?

Rather than check each individual vowel, consider a lookup technique.  You could create a table (one for vowel, one for consonant) that maps each character to true or false.  There is also a bit mapping alternative that builds on the lookup table approach, where you exploit the layout of the ascii table to do very fast lookups via bit shifts and masks.

```
bool is_vowel(char ch) {
    auto lowercase_pos = (ch | 0x20) - 96;
    if (static_cast<unsigned char>(lowercase_pos) > 31) {
       return false;
    }
    constexpr std::uint32_t vowel_mask = (1 << 1) | (1 << 5) | (1 << 9) | (1 << 15) | (1 << 21);
    return (vowel_mask & (std::uint32_t{1} << lowercase_pos)) != 0;
}
```

---

```
specific_count(range)
    count = 0
    for each element in the range
        if element is what we're looking for
            count = count + 1
    return count
```

Learn the various [`<algorithm>`s](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm).  You'll notice that both your functions have the same structure as the pseudocode above.  It turns out, this is a common algorithm in C++ ([`std::count_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count)).  You should be aware of this library as you learn more about functions and specifically lambdas (objects that behave like functions and can be passed around into functions as arguments).

Answer (score 0):

You can use standard algorithms to implement vowel or consonant count, e.g.,

```
int vowel_count(const std::string& s)
{
    return std::count_if(s.begin(), s.end(), [](char c) { 
        return c == 'a' || c == 'e' || c == 'i' || c == 'o' || c == 'u'; }
    );
}
```

Clearly, you can apply the same idea for counting consonants (or even implement that in terms of vowel counting, i.e., every character that is *not* a vowel *is* a consonant, but this requires you to trust the input to be sane).